# svn command line utility will not work if full file name is longer then 256 characters

Tags: svn

I cannot create working copy from command line using svn utility if resulting full file names for some files are too long.
But I can successfully create working copy from TortoiseSVN or from Subclipse.
Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround, you can `subst` your working copy to a drive letter to keep down the path length:

```
C:\Users\Me\SVN\My\Cool\Repository\With\A\Very\Long\Path> subst S: .
C:\Users\Me\SVN\My\Cool\Repository\With\A\Very\Long\Path> S:
S:> svn up
```

Answer (score 7):

This isn't really a limitation of the svn client but of the windows console: relative paths can't exceed MAX_PATH (254) chars when expanded.

And unlike some commenter here claims, it is not an oversight of the svn developers to forget about MAX_PATH. Because: if you pass full paths instead of relative ones, the commands will work.

So, instead of

```
cd C:\some\...\very\long\path
svn up .
```

run

```
svn up c:\some\...\very\long\path
```

and it should work just fine.

Comment: So we need to do it(svn up path) in all directories in our project?

Comment: yes, or shorten the paths to less than 254 chars, either by really shortening them (renaming) or using SUBST on a subfolder and then use the substed drive as the path.

Comment: Argh. I'm sorry. And now I can't even delete that answer anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing the following in your current directory:

```
svn co http://xxx/repo1
```

Give it the full target path like this:

```
svn co http://xxx/repo1 E:\abc\pqr\xyz\abc\pqr\xyz\repo1
```

Comment: Works! Thank you! I thought it was windows file system limitation.

Comment: This worked for me as well - even after trying the registry edit to use long file paths it was still failing.

Answer (score 0):

If your command line is in fact the Cygwin bash, then you could have hit this bug:

http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/11064
or
http://old.nabble.com/file-name-too-long-td22189828.html

which in fact is, that Cygwin can't handle paths with lengths over 255 chars. (In addition to Stefan's answer: Neither absolute nor relative paths are possible here.) Cygwin 1.7, which is beta since half a year, seems to fix this.

Comment: No - it is not Cygwin.
I use svn from FAR or from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Ubuntu system when trying to checkout a repository with very long filenames. However, I found out that my problem was related to the encryption of my home drive, as explained here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2258374